# How to match multiple groups of text terms?

Tags: python, text-mining

I'm doing a text mining task now and I have the following question:

**How to match multiple groups of text terms using Python?**

I have two sides group, one side is book group and the other side is document group. Each group has its terms (T) and contain many items that have their own terms (t). Take one group each side for example:

```
Book group 1 ＜T1, T2, T3, T4 ＞

b1 ＜t1, t2, t3 ＞

b2 ＜t1, t2, t3 ＞

b3 ＜t1, t2, t3 ＞



Book group 2 ＜ T2, T3, T4, T5 ＞

b4 ＜t2, t5, t8 ＞

b5 ＜t7, t9, t10 ＞

b6 ＜t4, t6, t8 ＞
```

---

```
Document group 1 ＜T1, T2, T3, T4 ＞

d1 ＜t1, t2, t3 ＞

d2 ＜t1, t4, t5 ＞

d3 ＜t2, t3, t5 ＞
```

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMN7x.png)

---

How do I match the groups if they have the same terms, i.e. Book group 1 = Document group 1?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I guess you are looking for the `set` data type, try to run `help(set)` on the REPL.

Comment: Maybe try regular expressions?

Comment: first thing first, i'm confused, why in your picture everywhere is < t1, t2, t3 >. Are they all the same ? At least use different notation if they are different

Comment: @Nexus sorry for that confusion, most of the terms are different (they are group by K-means clustering), thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @yichun then this isn't really a programming question per say ... When you have defined your methodology and get stuck on the implementation, that's when you post here

Comment: @yichun can I edit your question for more accurate?  When you say "How do I match the groups if they have the same terms?" meaning you don't care about items of the Book as well as items of the Documents. So if I have ＜T1, T2, T3, T4...＞ = ＜T1, T2, T3, T4...＞ then Book group 1 = Document group 1

Comment: @Nexus sure~ Thanks for your help.

Comment: @yichun see the edited question

Comment: @Nexus I really thanks for your help! But I have one question, because the book group terms and the document group terms maybe not the same completely. so maybe I have to use "similar".

Comment: Then it comes from your requirement. Do you want to classify it as "matched" , if  the book group terms and the document group terms maybe not the same completely? How do you want to match ?

Comment: @Nexus I don't know whether I can use dot product or not, I think I have to think about it...